# Is there an idiomatic way of chaining Option in Rust?

Tags: rust, optional-chaining

When deserializing deeply nested structures (e.g. from JSON), it's not uncommon to have to traverse multiple `Option` types.

For example:

```
let foo = Foo {
    x: Some(Bar {
        y: Some(Baz {
            z: Some(42),
        })
    })
};
```

Is there an idiomatic way of chaining Option to access deeply nested values?

So far I have the following, but neither are as concise as `foo.x?.y?.z` in other languages that support optional-chaining:

```
let z = foo.x.as_ref().and_then(|x| x.y.as_ref()).and_then(|y| y.z);
let z = foo.x.as_ref().and_then(|x| x.y.as_ref()?.z);
let z = (|| foo.x.as_ref()?.y.as_ref()?.z)();
```

---

It looks like the [`try_block`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/try-blocks.html) feature might be a good fit, but it's currently unstable.

```
let z = try { foo.x.as_ref()?.y.as_ref()?.z };
```

Comment: The immediately-invoked closure is probably the way to go for now. It will all be inlined during optimization, so there shouldn't be any performance hit.

Comment: (non-rust dev coming here from the main page), why can't `let z = foo.x.as_ref()?.y.as_ref()?.z` work directly? Why doe sit need to be wrapped in an immediately-evaluated closure?

Comment: @Alexander `?` in Rust isn't for null-coalescing, it is for error propagation. It is an early-exit-on-error operator and as such depends on the enclosing function.

Comment: @Alexander Because `?` will _return from the whole function with `None`_ if its operand is `None`.

Comment: I'm leaning towards the closure option. If it's too "ugly", I guess I can always create a new `try!` macro to hide it.

Comment: This is pretty subjective, but I would probably go for a `and_then`-chain over the immediately-invoked-closure. The latter is not very common in my experience and I'd have to double-take to see what its doing.

Comment: The very fact that you have these deeply nested structures is a bit of a smell, IMHO.

Comment: @eggyal If you ever work with REST APIs, those JSON responses can become very deep. Look at the number of levels in [Stack Exchange's API to get your inbox](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-inbox#filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you say, the `try` block would be perfect for this.

In the meantime you can take advantage of the fact that `?` works in functions, and wrap your expression in a closure and call it:

```
let z = (|| foo.x.as_ref()?.y.as_ref()?.z )();
```

You can write a simple macro to make it a bit nicer:

```
macro_rules! tryit {
    ($($e: tt)+) => {
        (|| { $($e)+ })()
    }
}
```

Which works basically the same as the `try` block:

```
let z = tryit! { foo.x.as_ref()?.y.as_ref()?.z };
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option if you don't like the immediately called closure is to use a crate like [`map_for`](https://crates.io/crates/map_for) or [`mdo`](https://crates.io/crates/mdo). Example with `map_for`:

```
use map_for::option::FlatMap;
let z = map_for!{
    x <- foo.x.as_ref();
    y <- x.y.as_ref();
    => y.z }:
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the `map_for` crate.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use destructuring with `if let`:

```rust
struct Foo {
    x: Option<Bar>,
}
struct Bar {
    y: Option<Baz>,
}
struct Baz {
    z: Option<i32>,
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo {
        x: Some(Bar {
            y: Some(Baz { z: Some(42) }),
        }),
    };

    if let Foo {
        x: Some(Bar {
            y: Some(Baz { z: Some(num) }),
        }),
    } = &foo
    {
        println!("contains number: {}", num);
    }
}
```

```
contains number: 42
```

Comment: I think this is an excellent use of destructuring and could certainly be used with the example provided, but isn't technically chaining of `Option`. You can kind of get a similar outcome with `let z = if let ... { Some(z) } else { None }`, but it's still really destructuring.